# why isn't there a -g option(gdb) when i execute make even if i wrote it in makefile

Tags: makefile, gdb

I am writting a makefile for my tiny project,here is my makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
DEPS = parse.h y.tab.h
OBJ = y.tab.o lex.yy.o parse.o 
FLAGS = -g -Wall
LDFLAGS = -lpthread

default:all

all: lisod

lex.yy.c: lexer.l
    flex $^

y.tab.c: parser.y
    yacc -d $^

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS)  -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
example: $(OBJ) example.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

lisod: lisod.o csapp.o $(OBJ)   $(LDFLAGS) 
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(FLAGS)
# hello:
#   echo hello
clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o example lex.yy.c y.tab.c y.tab.h lisod
```

but when i execute make,it appears that no -g option,thus i can't debug with gdb
here is part of the output of make:

```
gcc -I.   -c -o lisod.o lisod.c
gcc -I.   -c -o csapp.o csapp.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when i execute make,it appears that no -g option,thus i can't debug with gdb

If you look carefully at your output, you will realize that the issue is not so much the `-g` flag specifically, but that the pattern rule you've provided is not being used *at all*.  The fact that the `-I.` option appears first instead of last establishes this.

What you are getting is the default rule for building .o files from corresponding .c files.  Rules you provide override built-in ones when both apply, but in `make`'s analysis, your pattern rule does not (always) apply because it designates prerequisites (at least `y.tab.h`) that may not initially exist and for which there is no build rule.  (See [How Patterns Match](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html#Pattern-Match) in the GNU Make manual.)

You're in fact running into a classic problem with `make`'s model of the world: it doesn't deal very cleanly with recipes that generate multiple outputs that serve as prerequisites for other rules.  You might be interested in [the Automake manual's discussion of this topic](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Multiple-Outputs.html), which is mostly addressed generically at conforming `make` implementations, and which provides a series of increasingly complex (and increasingly flexible) rules.  This simple pattern is recommended as "enough for most cases":

```
y.tab.c: parser.y
    yacc -d $^

# Add this, so make knows where y.tab.h comes from:
y.tab.h: y.tab.c

# I assume that parse.h is an ordinary source, not a generated one

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Note that I moved the `CFLAGS` to the beginning of the compile command instead of the end.  Though it probably does not make a difference in your case, it is not entirely stylistic, as the order of options on the build command line is significant.  That effects link commands greatly, but it can effect compile commands too, depending on the options involved.

**Update:**

As long as you're relying on feature specific to GNU `make` (pattern rules) anyway, however, you might as well make *full* use of them.  As @MadScientist observed in comments, GNU `make` treats pattern rules with multiple targets differently than it (and other `make`s) treat ordinary rules with multiple targets: it understands and expects one execution of the rule's recipe to create *all* the targets matched to one set of prerequisites via the pattern.

Thus, if you're going to use pattern rules at all, then as MS observes, this is even better than the above "enough for most cases" alternative:

```
%.tab.c %.tab.h : parser.%
    yacc -d $^

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: In this particular case you can use a pattern rule, which _does_ understand multiple output files: `%.tab.h %.tab.c : parser.% ; yacc -d $<`.  But if your output and input files are not related by some aspect of the filename it does get tricky.

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist, I had not previously appreciated that detail of pattern rules.  I have updated this answer to include that information.

Comment: not totally understand but it really works,thank you!